# get Json data (Showing error - 'Request is not excuted')

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

get Json data (Showing error - 'Request  is not excuted')
How to make a request executed code.

country.js

```
$("#btn-id").click(function() {
 //get data    
$.getJSON("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", 
function(json) {
//Empty div if clicked agian
$("#data-id").html('')
//loop through it
json.data.forEach(function(jd) {
  //append data in div 
  $("#data-id").append(jd.id + "--" + jd.email + '<br>');
})
});
});
```

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>The jQuery Example</title>
  <script src="country.js"></script>
 </head>

  <body>
<form>
  <input type="button" id ="btn-id" value = "Click to Load Data"  />
   <div id="data-id"></div>
   </form>
   
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="country.js"></script>

   </body>
 </html>
```

get Json data (Showing error - 'Request  is not excuted')
How to make a request executed code.

Comment: Your code works fine. I put it in a snippet and i get the data and it gets printed to the page. What's not working?

Comment: I am submitting online where it says Request is not executed
Proposed grade: 50.00 / 100
Result Description
 Fail 1 : Request is not executed

Comment: Not sure what that means - the code works

Comment: The code works but I have to  change the code in a way that it send some Request